# Optparse of python

Tags: python, optparse

I am new to optparse of python and tried the following:

```
def plot():
    x=[1,2,3]
    y=[4,5,6]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.savefig('trial.pdf')

parser=OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-p", "--plot", action="callback", callback=plot)
(options, args)=parser.parse_args()
```

I typed `python3 parse.py -p` in the terminal and it gave:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firstparse.py", line 15, in <module>
    (options, args)=parser.parse_args()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 1386, in parse_args
    stop = self._process_args(largs, rargs, values)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 1430, in _process_args
    self._process_short_opts(rargs, values)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 1535, in _process_short_opts
    option.process(opt, value, values, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 784, in process
    self.action, self.dest, opt, value, values, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 804, in take_action
    self.callback(self, opt, value, parser, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: plot() takes 0 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I do not understand well about the positional arguments error. Could anyone tell me where I wrong?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion made by the incompleteness of the question just now. I have edited the question to give a better view of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html#defining-a-callback-option):

When using `callback`, you supply a function that is used to process the incoming argument, this function is called with four arguments: `option, opt_str, value, parser`

> `option`
>
> is the Option instance that’s calling the callback
>
> `opt_str`
>
> is the option string seen on the command-line that’s triggering the callback...
>
> `value`
>
> is the argument to this option seen on the command-line...
>
> `parser`
>
> is the OptionParser instance driving the whole thing, mainly useful because you can access some other interesting data through its instance attributes...

Essentially you are trying to process the argument from command line into its value by processing it through `plot` function.

I suspect you are trying to choose, action (such a `plot`) to run from the command line, so perhaps more like:

```
parser=ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", "--plot", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.plot is True:
    plot()
```

Note: `optparse` has been deprecated since 3.2, you should nowadays be using `argparse`.